# pulseaudio - Run a command on card profile switch

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, audio-recording

How can I run a script when pulseaudio changes profile of a bluetooth device from "Off" to "A2DP Source" and vice-versa? I want to record from the source and stop the recording when profile is "Off". Thanks.

Screenshot of pavucontrol:

[image: Screenshot of pavucontrol]

Comment: Which program do you use to record audio ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I have used Audacity in the past. But i have read that it is not very accessible through the command line and people at the audacity forums have suggest another program name SoX. I havent used that though

Comment: Does ```pactl list sinks short | grep -i bluez``` return anything in your system while you're using the bluetooth device?

Comment: If so , does [this script](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/drCSFQygxw/) work for you ? If yes , I can post it as the answer , otherwise please tell me the error messages.Note that you have to install **sox** and **pulseaudio-utils** first.

Comment: Or you can replace the **bluez** in the command above with **Fidelity** for example.

Comment: And as a solution for your previous question, you can tamper that script to **begin** recording when  the device gets connected .

Comment: @ParsaMousavi `pactl list sinks short | grep -i bluez` isn't returning anything when I'm playing audio. But replacing with `sources` returns `88 bluez_source.38_30_F9_A6_BE_BD.a2dp_source module-bluez5-device.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz RUNNING`

Comment: So replace that also in the script.